# Apache Spark What is the difference between requiredChildDistribution and outputPartitioning?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, catalyst-optimizer

In Apache Spark, each physical operator in the physical plan has 4 properties:

- outputPartitioning
- outputOrdering​
- requiredChildDistribution
- requiredChildOrdering

But aren't outputPartioning and requiredChildDistribution the same? How are they different and what do they fundamentally represent? Same for outputOrdering and requiredChildOrdering?